# Remote gradle debug on build.gradle file from Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gradle

So in Windows in the comand line I wrote

> set GRADLE_OPTS=-Xdebug
>   -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=y

Then I get:

```
C:\Project>gradle main
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
```

Then I put a breakpoint in the gradle.build file
[image]

and at last from Eclipse IDE

[image]

And I get

[image]

why this happend? So I can't debug gradle files, I can only debug java,groovy.. files?

Answer (score 5):

It's a known limitation that Gradle build scripts can't currently be debugged in IDEs. I'm not aware of the specific error though. Usually the debugger just doesn't stop at the breakpoint (but it will stop at breakpoints for user-defined plugin/task classes and Gradle classes).

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to add the Grade sources to set breakpoints on?

Comment: You can either do it manually in the usual Eclipse way, or, depending on how you integrate with Eclipse, script it in the Gradle build. I don't have code ready for the latter.

Comment: Works well with IntelliJ not Eclipse